# Why do i not recieve emails from my contacts form

Tags: wordpress, web, contacts, contact-form

Im trying to set up a contact form, but the is with from to email. From users perspective it says that message was sent, but i dont get any emails. The problem is that I cant understand how to setup a "From email" which is used to send this messages. I have already tried to use no-reply@ and admin@ emails but they aint working. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "WP mail SMTP" plugin to set up the from email. You can check out this tutorial for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyHO4yYrsbs